# how to make objects from associated models in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

***I have resident model***

```
class Resident < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_one :user
end
```

and User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :resident
 end
```

I want to create  user from the roll_number attribute of the Resident.I have a form which asks for user  some values including roll_number field  and if the roll number matches to the Residents table's roll_number attribute the  User object is created.

*We already have residents(list of students with there roll_numbers residing in hostel) in our database added by the admin.Now when the student signups in our application by using our signup form,form only asks for email,password and roll_number. and if the roll_number matches to the roll_number of the existing resident table the user gets created.*

**Attributes of User table**

id:autogenerated

roll_number:string

email:string

password:string

resident_id:references from resident table

**Attributes of the Resident table**

id:autogenerated

roll_number:string

name:string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

```
def create
  resident = Resident.find_by(roll_number: user_params[:roll_number])
  if resident.present?
    @user = resident.create_user(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email
      UserMailer.account_activation(@user).deliver_now
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  else
    flash[:info] = "Please enter a correct roll number."
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

You need to check how you can access the `roll_number` value from params, I cannot figure it out because I don't know how your form looks like. Also you need to handle the case if the `roll_number` doesn't match.

Hope that helps!

Comment: There's a signup page for user registration with  fields : roll number,email,password,password conformation.
Now when  user enters details it must check the roll number if it is present in resident table or not ..also if present then create the user according to the resident ..bcz it is a one to one relation ship btw them.
the solution you have provided with is giving error bcz  you are finding the resident with  resident's id but  the user ain't giving the  resident id at the time of signing up. what he is giving to us at the time of signup that is related to the resident model is roll_number

Comment: User controller :
https://justpaste.it/shjl

Signup page:
https://justpaste.it/shjn

Comment: What if a roll number is not present in the resident?

Comment: roll number is compulsory.. bcz we will identify the student ( students  registered in hostels )when they sign up our application ..
roll_number is the main attribute that is given by the user when they signup.. and we also have the list of students registered in hostel as a **As a resident table** created by admin.. the user only gets created if the roll_number is matched from the signup page that the user has entered. and then we have all the details of the user in resident table .. we will use those details of users for further use !

Answer (score 0):

in user.rb

```
before_create :match_resident

def match_resident
  resident = Resident.find_by(roll_number: self.roll_number)
  if resident.blank?
    raise "Invalid roll number"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check & validate for roll number for resident and create user in UsersController#Create method like :

```
def create
    resident = Resident.find_by(params[:user][:roll_number])
    if resident.present?
      @user = resident.create_user(roll_number: resident.roll_number)
      if @user.save
        # Handle a successful save.
        @user.send_activation_email
        UserMailer.account_activation(@user).deliver_now
        flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
        redirect_to root_url
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: then what's the matter of adding the resident_id to user table... how both the models are relating to each other then?

Comment: when you do resident.user.new it will add resident_id auto from resident object.

Comment: @Nischaynamdev I have editted my answer according to your provided justPaste link you can replace your userscontroller#create method with the method in my code it will work perfect.

Comment: @Nischaynamdev yes and editted the answer according that code.

Comment: I can mark  one answer  only ..but two of you have given same answers.. so I chose the person who answered first ..